# Implementing Floating action buttons in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, floating-action-button

I imported the design library and android support v7 app-compact library from sdk.

then I wrote code for Floating action button as follows

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

But shows the error,
The following class could not be found:`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`

help me on this.

Comment: add the dependencies if not... clean the project.. and run it.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/31431076/3981656 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/30652875/3981656

Comment: add design library from the sdk to your project as dependency, clean the project and try running it again

Comment: @Mit how to add as dependency in eclipse please help

Comment: @sourabhbans  how to add as dependency in eclipse please help

Comment: @tenten Right click on project... Properties... select android section.... click on add libraries .. select Design support.. click on apply and Ok..

Comment: @sourabhbans no such path in eclipse :(

Comment: @tenten .. follow the process ..
1. remove the design support library from eclipse.
2. import it again.. NOTE : check the option copy into work space while import it.
3. Right click on Design support library >> Properties >>select Android tab >> check the option of  Is Library >> change the compile sdk version if required. >> Click Apply and OK.
4. Now right click on your app project >> Properties >> select Android tab >>click on add >> select the design support library and click apply.

Comment: @sourabhbans I already did that :(